# Can we deliver an updated text file (any non versioned file) in an MSP

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msi-patch

Step 1: I have an updated msi which has a new text file : env.info
an msp generated out of it places this text file in the folder.

Step 2: I have updated this text file and generated an msp again, now this msp doesn't replace the new file.

Any idea how to handle non versioned files in an msp?

Comment: precisely, what can i do to have this file replaced in the installed folder (using an msp) every time it changes

Comment: Have a look at the REINSTALLMODE property covered in the following page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the overwrite rules prohibit replacing non-versioned files that have been updated since the install:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

and you can verify this if you produce an MSI log of the patch install.

The safest solution, as here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2013/05/23/updating-the-last-modified-time-to-prevent-windows-installer-from-updating-an-unversioned-file/

is to change the times on the file to let it be replaced. That's because the other solution is to set the REINSTALLMODE to overwrite all files - this may not always be the write thing to do if you end up replacing a higher versioned file with a lower version.

A better design for this issue is to have the keypath of the data file be set to a versioned binary, companion files.

Comment: can we add MsiFileHash to the unversioned file and generate an msi? will this work?

Comment: ignore my previous question. but i have another question- Pointing to my original question, my msp1 places this file in istallation folder, an msp2 with the updated env.info file doesn't replace the older file. I checked that the msihash is different for both the files. Is this not sufficient for the msp2 to replace the file?

Comment: i would want the usage of companion file. I researched on support sites but couldn't find any

Comment: i would want the usage of companion file. I researched on support sites but couldn't find any